# Docker php starting containers with parameters

Tags: php, docker

I need to start `docker` container with parameters in `sf2` app
in shell I'm doing it with

```
docker run -d -p 88:80 -p 3309:3306 c413a7015052
```

And I'm trying to do the same with `docker-php` but don't know how to add parameters and just cant get it to work. Now I'm starting containers with

```
$dock = $this->get('app.docker');
$containerManager = $dock->getConnection()->getContainerManager();
$containerManager->start($id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is solution

```
    $hostConfig = new HostConfig();
    $portMap = new \ArrayObject();
    $portBinding = new PortBinding();
    $portBinding->setHostIp();
    $portBinding->setHostPort('88');
    $portMap['80/tcp'] = [$portBinding];
    $hostConfig->setPortBindings($portMap);
    $containerConfig = new ContainerConfig();
    $containerConfig->setHostConfig($hostConfig);
```